# Logging the usernames of all the users that have logged in today

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I am using Spring security plugin for grails to authenticate and authorize users. I want to keep track of how many total logins were done today. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [the docs](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/) about the plugin's support for events. If you're using 3.x the event docs are [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#events) and the 2.x event docs are [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/events.html).

There's no higher-level support for anything like capturing today's logins or aggregating, but you can easily do that in your event handler.